# .htaccess - Hiding a directory in the URL while preserving other files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I developed a giant studio of tools and each tool has its own directory in the /tools/ folder. So if you have a tool named *example*, the URL would be /studio-dir/tools/example/.

I'm trying to hide the /tools/ directory from URLs, while making sure other files outside of the /tools/ directory still work. For example, the /index.php file and /admin/ directory should remain.

I tried this, but it only caused massive 404 errors on everything. I know it's probably waay off, I suck with rewriting URLs. :P

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tools/
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /tools/$1 [L]
```

If you're still confused, I want:

> http://www.example.com/studio/**tools/example/index.php**

To be able to load as:

> http://www.example.com/studio/**example/index.php**

Whilst still keeping the /tools/ directory, and allowing other files outside of the /tools/ directory to load.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    /studio/(.*) /studio/tools/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

The problem is it will not work if the requested file is both in the studio-folder and the tools-folder.

But there no way to prevent this, as the server never knows if an URL is meant to refer to /studio/tools/ or /studio/

Edit: You can remove /tools/ from the visible urls like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    /studio/(.*) /studio/tools/$1    [L]
    RewriteRule    /studio/tools/(.*) /studio/$1    [L,R=302]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Nice! Works wonders. Would there also be a way to force a redirect to remove /tools/ if it's found in the URL?

Comment: See my edit for this. Try it out, though, I am not sure if it will result in an infinit loop or not.

Comment: It doesn't loop indefinitely. It doesn't redirect either, lol. But it's okay, I got it all working with the original rule you posted. :)

Comment: @User3515241 Then I urge you to read this guide carefully, it will help you to ask better questions in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

In this example there is not 404 but it only works to hide only one dir

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dirname/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^dirname/)^(.*)$ /dirname/$1 [L,NC]
```