# Url rewriting for hiding folder name and open it without folder name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hv used all my uls in action with root directory now i cant change all of them so i need to rewrite my home url which hides folder name and if someone opens that domain then data saved in that folder must also be opened but folder name should not be displayed in url i.e. i have this

http://example.com/foldername

.I want to change this in as

http://example.com

but it should automatically take foldername data .How this can be achieved
by using ".htaccess" file

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

This is the .htaccess file i am currently using

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? Is it inside `/foldername/`?

Comment: This may help you. Have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642122/htaccess-hiding-a-directory-in-the-url-while-preserving-other-files

Comment: Yes . You are right so i can create a new htaccess file to solve my problem and this file can be retained as it is  @anubhava.

Comment: This htaccess can be used in `foldername` but you'll need another htaccess in root

Comment: Yes @anubhava so can you tell me how this can be achieved . No issue with another htaccess

Comment: How to use it @NikhileshDutta ??

Answer (score 2):

Keep this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!foldername/)(.*)$ foldername/$1 [L,NC]
```

Then have this simplified code in `/fodlername/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I have added your code for root file but for folderfile do i have to replace your code with mine or append it to mine . Can you add this to my htaccess file . It will be of great help .

Comment: You can replace all of the .htaccess in question code with my suggested `/fodlername/.htaccess`

Comment: This "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.5.19 Server at rustagisamaj.com Port 80"

Comment: I need to be offline for some work, will attend this in an hour

Comment: I think you need to edit the file where already some conditions are given.

Comment: Ok but please do reply . its really omportant for my project .Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111139/discussion-between-anubhava-and-php-devp).

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.htaccess` file like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /foldername/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^foldername/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yoursite.com$
RewriteRule !^foldername/ foldername%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: you r right. but if the question not clear and the issue not repeated , for example so many people here ask regarding this issue but up to redirect every thing at specific directory to parent or root but here the difference is that he want to prevent browsing original path directly and when they explore it , it will be hidden , so from the discussion above i think that the questioner know what he need  so i write it without comment , thanks for your comment

Comment: The answer should also be able to help others with the same problem, not just the original asker, just keep that in mind ;)